# Why it's not early binding?

Tags: java, late-binding, early-binding

```
class a{
    void display(){
        System.out.println("display1");
    }
}

class b extends a{
    void display(){
        System.out.println("display1b");
    }
}

class c extends b{
    void display(){
        System.out.println("display1c");
    }
}

class ab {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        a mn=new c();
        mn.display();
    }
}
```

it's example of late binding,but when i compile this code and then decompile using cavaj
i found this code ab.java:

```
class ab {
    ab(){}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        c c1 = new c();
        c1.display();
    }
}
```

If it's late binding then compiler not must should know that display() method  is from c class ,
but here it's know because it replace
 a mn=new c();
  with
   c c1 = new c();
 ,so this is early binding??

Comment: Please format your code and respect naming conventions.

Comment: You are using a local variable so the compiler knows its scope and can perform these optimizations, which don't affect the behavior of the code. Perform the same operations making `c1` an attribute and check what happens then.

Comment: @SJuan76  and how I make c1 an attribute?

Comment: you override the display. so no need to refer class a display method. because c is a child of a.

Comment: Define `mn` outside the `main` method. Do not make it private. Anyway, if you  don't know what an attribute is, probably you should first concentrate in learning the basis of the language before exploring its guts.

Comment: @SJuan76 got the attribute but still confused,this happens because main method is static ??